# Very old items in review queue

Tags: support

Just about half an hour ago, my review queue jumped up to over 120 items. I started going through them but most of them are quite old, like Late Answers from 2009 - 2012. I did recently pass 4k reputation.

Is this normal? Should I go through and process about 120 late answers from years ago as I find the time? Why would they not have been addressed by high rep users prior to now?

Comment: Also why when there is over 40 review tasks for me to do does the system tell me the following? "Thank you for reviewing 20 late answers today; come back in 13 hours to continue reviewing."

Comment: I had some time and could have done them if the system allowed it.

Comment: @NeilMeyer The 20 reviews a day is a way to prevent the robo reviewing. I wouldn't worry too much about all of this, just do your 20 a day and the queue will empty quite quickly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because SE has raised the rep requirement for late answers. See [Can we raise the bar for reputation for late answers to bypass the review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue/267080#267080)

Comment: I don't understand the whole system well enough to connect that fact with my situation or see how I should respond to my now much larger queue. Do I understand correctly that users with a certain rep will not have their answers go in the late answer queue no matter how late their answer is, and that rep cutoff is what has been changed?

Comment: Oh, so did *everyone* just get a bunch of late answers dumped into their queues across all of Stack Exchange?

Comment: Yup - that's not many here, but around 800-odd on SO

Comment: @ToddWilcox users with rep less than 50, will have their answers go to the queue